# Create Pandas DataFrame from space separated String

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a string:

```
              C1     C2                       DATE     C4     C5         C6      C7
0            0.0    W04  2021-01-08 00:00:00+00:00      E    EUE         C1     157
1            0.0    W04  2021-01-08 00:00:00+00:00      E    AEU         C1     157
2            0.0    W04  2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      E   SADA         H1     747
3            0.0    W04  2021-01-04 00:00:00+00:00      E   SSEA         H1     747
4            0.0    W04  2021-01-05 00:00:00+00:00      E   GPEA         H1     747
```

It sure looks like a Pandas DataFrame because it comes from one.
I need to convert it into a Pandas DataFrame.

I tried the following:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(string_file),sep=r"\s+")
```

but it messes with the columns and separates the DATE column into 2 columns.

Comment: Use `sep=r"\s\s+"`

Comment: @SayandipDutta thank you, it works on the body, but the header is still messed up. It looks right aligned and one-space-separated

Comment: I copied this data and tried reading using `StringIO` and `sep=r'\s\s+'`, I can't reproduce your problem. Works fine for me.

Comment: pandas has [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) where you can specify the breakpoints for columns. this looks like a solution for your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, recreate the string:

```
s = """
              C1     C2                       DATE     C4     C5         C6      C7
0            0.0    W04  2021-01-08 00:00:00+00:00      E    EUE         C1     157
1            0.0    W04  2021-01-08 00:00:00+00:00      E    AEU         C1     157
2            0.0    W04  2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      E   SADA         H1     747
3            0.0    W04  2021-01-04 00:00:00+00:00      E   SSEA         H1     747
4            0.0    W04  2021-01-05 00:00:00+00:00      E   GPEA         H1     747
"""
```

Now, you can use `Pandas.read_csv` to import a buffer:

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r"\s\s+")
```

From what I can tell, this results in exactly the DataFrame that you are looking for:

[image: Screenshot of resulting DataFrame]

You may want to convert the `DATE` column to `datetime` values as well:

```
df['DATE'] = df.DATE.astype('datetime64')
```

Comment: Something to consider when following this method is that you may run into issues if the column name is longer than the data is being inputted. In that case, you may have to manually add some spaces in the header row in order for the columns to properly align with data.